# HTML Select Option width problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a select element in form, and contains the time zones. The problem is, that the name of the time zones do not fit inside the select element and this happen:

[image]

HTML part of  the code I have:

```
         <div class="rowElem noborder"><label>Time Zone:</label>
        <div class="formRight240">
          <select id="p_tz_key_i" name="p_tz_key_i" class="validate[required]" style="width:800px;" >
          <option value>Select Time Zone...</option>
    <option value="1124">Dateline Standard Time, Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
    <option value="1125">Samoa Standard Time, Midway Is, Samoa</option>
    <option value="1126">Hawaiian Standard Time, Hawaii</option>
    <option value="1127">Alaskan Standard Time, Alaska</option>
    <option value="1128">Pacific Standard Time, Pacific Time, (US & Canada); Tijuana</option>
</select>
```

So I have try inline css and is not working. Don´t know how to fix this

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddle?

Comment: are you using some kind of jquery library to style the select ?

Comment: That's not an ordinary drop down list. Either you're using a fancy browser that doesn't really support `<select>` tags properly,  or got some client side scripting messing the drop down lists. Anyway, nothing you can do in HTML or CSS to fix it.

Comment: You are right we have js files call forms, this is a big proyect and don't know what is in there, probably that is the problem.. there is anything I can do to overwrite this js affecting my html?